# Attempting to remove compression from an MSI causes its files to disappear

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to build an MSP patch for a program that's currently deployed using an MSI package.  I've been able to successfully generate a PCP file using the following (slightly-redacted) WiX code, based on an example from the [WiX documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/patch_building.html).

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <PatchCreation
        Id="D25F1136-2BEE-4A82-9236-7261067D4BDC"
        CleanWorkingFolder="yes"
        OutputPath="XYZ.pcp"
        WholeFilesOnly="yes"
    >
        <PatchInformation />
        <PatchMetadata
            AllowRemoval="no"
            Classification="Major Upgrade"
            Description="XYZ Update"
            DisplayName="XYZ Update"
            ManufacturerName="XYZ"
            MoreInfoURL="http://www.contoso.com/qr/XYZ.html"
            TargetProductName="$(var.ProductName)"
        />
        <Family Name="PrsnPtch">
            <UpgradeImage Id="LatestImage" SourceFile="new_msi_dir\XYZ.msi">
                <TargetImage Id="OldImage" Order="1" SourceFile="old_msi_dir\XYZ.msi" />
            </UpgradeImage>
        </Family>
        <PatchSequence PatchFamily="XyzPatch" Supersede="yes" />
    </PatchCreation>
</Wix>
```

and a build script set up to call [msimsp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370324(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
msimsp -s "%PCPDIR%\XYZ.pcp" -p "%PCPDIR%\XYZ.msp" -l "%PCPDIR%\patch.log"
```

Unfortunately, the above command fails with the following error message:

> ERROR: UpgradedImages.MsiPath '[...]\XYZ.msi' is marked as having
>   compressed files (PID_WORDCOUNT property of Summary Information
>   stream). PatchWiz is unable to patch files compressed in a cabinet.

So I tried building an uncompressed version of the MSI by adding a CompressionLevel attribute to the [MediaTemplate element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/mediatemplate.html) in *its* WXS file.

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" CompressionLevel="none" />
```

For building the MSI itself, this is a success.  The resulting file is 3.7 times the size of the uncompressed original, and 7-Zip shows the files therein as having a compression method of “None”.  And I am able to successfully install the program on a VM.

The problem is that then I *still* get the “PatchWiz is unable to patch files compressed in a cabinet” error when running msimsp.

The culprit seems to be the Compressed attribute on the WXS [Package element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/package.html):

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" 
         Compressed="yes" 
         InstallScope="perMachine" 
         Description="XYZ Installer"/>
```

So naturally, I tried changing `Compressed="yes"` to `Compressed="no"` (with *no* other changes to this WXS file).  And this “works” as far as allowing msimsp to not give any errors.

But it introduces the serious problem that the MSI file is “empty”, its size having been reduced from about 3.6 MB to a mere 280 KB.  Viewing the archive in 7-Zip shows that it does not contain any of the files that it's supposed to install.  Viewing it in Orca shows a [Media table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369801(v=vs.85).aspx) with one row containing the values DiskId=1 and LastSequence=19, but nothing in the Cabinet column (the original MSI had an auto-generated “#cab1.cab” here).

Why would changing the Compression attribute make the CAB file go missing?  How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

This patch creation process does not work by using MSI files with embedded cabs or external cabs. It uses administrative images that you create using msiexec /a ..... This creates an MSI file together with all the external loose files in their appropriate directories. The patch creation process uses two of these admin images to generate the patch, the msp file, and it compares each corresponding file in each image to create the delta between the two products.

An administrative install is not an "install" - it's mainly just file extraction from the MSI into loose files in directories. This also marks the resultant MSI file as having "no files" in it - it's just the tables - so the patch creation process will complain if it finds this or anything indicating the files are in a cab. It needs separate loose files.

Once you have two administrative images the patch creation process (using a PCP file) runs against the two images comparing each file for changes and generating an actual patch, an msp file.

(Note that there is an IgnoreMissingSrcFiles setting in the PCP TargetImages table that allows missing files to be ignored while the patch is being created - it would make no sense to have this setting if the patch creation process used CAB files because all the files would always be there. )

Comment: I'm not sure what assumptions you may have that you're not talking about, but creating patches using admin images is nothing to do with how any product is installed.